# Is there a way to stream a live on Facebook from the flutter video conferencing app implemented using agora?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, live-streaming, agora.io

I have a flutter application for live streaming, implemented using agora. I need to stream a video on Facebook from that application. Is there a way to implement that feature?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with Agora Media Push Rest Api but this is the paid service from agora so first you have to enable it from your agora dashboard and I was also facing this problem and after so many try and conversation with agora i finally able to success in this and you can check this post for Agora media push

https://www.codemicros.com/2022/12/agora-media-push-with-flutter-using.html